# How to center loading animation in nextjs using tailwind

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

Here is the code for **loading.jsx** element

```
import './loading.css'
export default function Loader() {
    return (
            <div className=" absolute grid h-screen justify-center content-center spinner">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
    )
}
```

And this is the code for Pgae.tsx

```
import Loader from './loading'

export default function Home() {
  return (
  <div className='bg-black p-5'>
      <h1 className='text-white'>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
  )
}
```

I just want to center the loading animation which is appearing top left of the page.

I wanted to center the laoding animation it, in the provided code it is showing at the top left of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your layout isn't exactly supporting what you want to do. Also, for justify-center to work, you need a display property like `flex` for that to take effect.

Nonetheless, I have modified your code to do exactly what you want to do. And I made the position to be fixed, rather than absolute so it stays on top of other components at all times.

**Edit**: According to the Github codebase provided, adding `fixed` and `top-0` was the gamechanger. Also added a backdrop blur to give it some more sleekness. You can remove.

Try this:

```
import './loading.css';

export default function Loader() {
  return (
    <div className="fixed top-0 h-screen w-full bg-black bg-opacity-70 backdrop-blur-sm flex flex-col justify-center items-center z-50">
      <div className="spinner">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: it's not adding it to the center, I have navbar at the top of the webpage which is dragging it to the bottom and not making it center exactly.

Comment: I tested a sample of this code on Tailwind Play and it worked well. I assume there are some peculiarities in your codebase. Maybe you can put a sample on codepen or stackblitz for us to see the issue exactly.

Comment: here's the code https://github.com/SahilDhingraa/xaibotix/

Comment: Okay I think I fixed it @SahilDhingra. What was missing was a position property. I added `top-0` to the loader's parent div and it's fixed properly now. Tried creating a Pull Request but no permissions. eYinka is my Github username. I'd try to edit the answer here as well. Hopefully it fixes your problem now :)

Comment: added your username to collaborators

Comment: there was a problem with the navbar but I fixed that by removing that z-index property

Comment: Pushed a PR for you. Should be fine there now :)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, I see an absolute positioning which will put the element in position relative to the parent in the top left corner, and you would need to use absolute values (TOP, LEFT, etc.) to reposition the element relative to the window or the parent `div`. I see also `grid` and `flex` on the same `div`. Use either and add the `flex` class to your code.

```
export default function Loader() {
    return (
            <div className="h-screen flex justify-center items-center spinner">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: not working still on the top left side

Comment: is the repository public for this project i could have a look at it ?

Comment: here's the code https://github.com/SahilDhingraa/xaibotix/